# Stopped martingale is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $M$ be a non-negative martingale starting at a>0 and consider a stopping time $$T=\inf\{t\colon M_t \geqslant K\}. K>a$$ We also assume that the martingale will reach $K$ in finite time almost surely. We know that $E[M_{t\land T}]=E[M_0]=0$, because the stopped martingale is a martingale. Further, $E[\mid M_{t\land T} \mid]$ is bounded from above uniformly by $K$, which allows me to apply the Dominated convergence theorem: 
$$E[M_T]=\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}E[M_{T \land t}]=E[M_0]=0.$$ However, we know that $E[M_T]=K\neq 0$ by the very definition of $T$.

> What went wrong with the above argumentation?

Comment: Why do you claim that $\mathsf E M_T = K$?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem

Comment: @TomekKania Because the process will take the value K at the stopping time.

Comment: @TomekKania sorry, I am on my phone so my answer seem to be little curt. I am fully aware of the theorem. But I am just confused if we take a martingale only on positives and then define a one side limit. This would make all the arguments valid since $E[|M_t|]=E[X_0]$ and it is indeed uniformly bounded. However, as the example shows, this is not a valid example to OST. I am not sure what went wrong here.

Comment: @TomekKania Can you tell your point? $M_t$ will be stopped if it reaches K. Then why should $M_T$ not be K?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute value of this martingale is actually not necessarily uniformly bounded; think of a 1-D simple random walk starting from 0. Under your stopping time, it could go all the way to negative infinity without being stopped.

Edit: After reading your comment that it is non-negative, it seems your assumptions themselves are contradictory to begin with. The only non-negative martingale starting from 0 can be, well, just 0. (i.e. $X_n = 0$ a.s.). Otherwise, you cannot have $\mathbb{E}X_n = 0$ if $X_n \geq 0$. As such, you are never going to reach K for K > 0.

Comment: But my martingale is assume to be non-negative.

Comment: Uh, so you have a martingale that is always 0 in expectation and non-negative? Isn't that then always just 0?

Comment: you are right, maybe I should amend it to $M_0=a$ and $K>a$.

Comment: Regardless, if you force your martingale to be non-negative, unless you stop when it hits 0, it wont be a martingale. (Think of conditioning on the first time it hits 0)

Comment: @quallenjäger: Also, try to not just change questions again and again; you should just write a new question otherwise you are invalidating all the previous answers given in a question.

Comment: Given a random walk $S_n$, define a martingale $M_n=\frac{e^{\theta S_n}}{cosh(\theta)^n}$ It is a non-negative martingale. There are a bunch of non-trivial non-negative martingale which is not stopped.

Comment: Your argument is not sufficient here. Define a stopping time $T:=inf\{n: S_n=1\}$. Since $0 \leq E[M_{T \land n} ] \leq e^\theta$ and $P(T<\infty)=1$, which can be shown with ease. This is the problem I am asking for.

Comment: @quallenjäger: Uh, what is the issue with $E[M_T] = 1$?